# git init creates directory in wrong location?

Tags: git, passwords

```
paladin1@locutus:~> ls -ld .password-store/
drwxrwxrwx 3 paladin1 users 4096 Dec  8 00:14 .password-store/
paladin1@locutus:~> cd .password-store/
paladin1@locutus:~/.password-store> env | grep GIT
paladin1@locutus:~/.password-store> git init
hint: Using 'master' as the name for the initial branch. This default branch name
hint: is subject to change. To configure the initial branch name to use in all
hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
hint: 
hint:   git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
hint: 
hint: Names commonly chosen instead of 'master' are 'main', 'trunk' and
hint: 'development'. The just-created branch can be renamed via this command:
hint: 
hint:   git branch -m <name>
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/paladin1/.git/
paladin1@locutus:~/.password-store> pass git init
fatal: cannot change to '/home/paladin1/.password-store': Permission denied
```

(I don't usually have 777 permissions on this directory; this is for troubleshooting.)

Why is git creating its repository in the parent directory and not where I told it to?

Comment: That's definitely odd. Do you have a front-end script or alias in the way of `git` that is moving the location?

Comment: Ahh - yes, it's firejailed. Apparently that was causing the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @torek asked a question in comments above,

git was running in firejail and didn't have directory access.